# How to superimpose two contour maps onto each other in matlab?

Tags: matlab, plot, contourf

I have two contour maps in Matlab and each of the two maps has a single curve specifying a single Z-value. I want to super impose the two contour maps so that I can find the single solution where the two z-value curves intersect. How could I go about super imposing the two contour maps?

```
 % the two contour maps are coded the exact same way, but with different z-values
 x = 0.05:0.05:1;
 y = 0.0:0.05:1;
 [X, Y] = meshgrid(x, y);
 % Z-value data is copied from excel and pasted into an array
 Z = [data]
 contourf(X, Y, Z);
 pcolor(X, Y, Z); hold on
 shading interp
 title();
 xlabel();
 ylabel();
 colorbar

 val = %z-value to plot onto colormap
 tol = %tolerance
 idxZval = (Z <= val+tol) & (Z >= val-tol);
 plot(X(idxZval), Y(idxZval))[enter image description here][1]
```

Comment: You clearly know how to use `hold on` so why doesn't plotting both on the same axes result in the superimposition you want?

Comment: @Will I didn't actually think of that! Thank you for your response!

Answer (score 3):

The end result you seek is possible using [`contourc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourc.html) or using [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) specifying the same contours (isolines).

This answer extends [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56798759/8239061) in **Approach 1** using [`contourc`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contourc.html) and provides a simple solution with [`contour`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/contour.html) in **Approach 2**.

You might ask "*Why Approach 1 when Approach 2 is so simple?*" 
Approach 1 provides a way to directly access the individual isolines in the event you require a numerical approach to searching for intersections.

## Approach 1

**Example Data:**

```
% MATLAB R2018b
x = 0:0.01:1;
y = 0:0.01:1;
[X,Y] = meshgrid(x,y);
Z = sqrt(X.^3+Y);                      % Placeholder 1
W = sqrt(X.*Y + X.^2 + Y.^(2/3));      % Placeholder 2
```

**Overlay Single Isoline from 2 Contour Plots**
Mimicking [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56798759/8239061) and using
`v = [.5 0.75 .85 1];    % Values of Z to plot isolines`
we can visualize these two functions, `Z`, and `W`, respectively.

[image: Two contour plots]

We can overlay the isolines since they share the same **(x,y)** domain. For example, they both equal **0.8** as displayed below.

[image: Overlay of isolines for Z, W, for value of 0.8]

```
val = 0.8;                     % Isoline value to plot (for Z & W)
Ck = contourc(x,y,Z,[val val]);
Ck2 = contourc(x,y,W,[val val]);
figure, hold on, box on
plot(Ck(1,2:end),Ck(2,2:end),'k-','LineWidth',2,'DisplayName',['Z = ' num2str(val)])
plot(Ck2(1,2:end),Ck2(2,2:end),'b-','LineWidth',2,'DisplayName',['W = ' num2str(val)])
legend('show')
```

---

**Overlay Multiple Isolines from 2 Contour Plots**
We can also do this for more isolines at a time.
[image: Overlay of multiple isolines]

```
v = [1 0.5];                   % Isoline values to plot (for Z & W)
figure, hold on, box on
for k = 1:length(v)
   Ck = contourc(x,y,Z,[v(k) v(k)]);
   Ck2 = contourc(x,y,W,[v(k) v(k)]);
   p(k) = plot(Ck(1,2:end),Ck(2,2:end),'k-','LineWidth',2,'DisplayName',['Z = ' num2str(v(k))]);
   p2(k) = plot(Ck2(1,2:end),Ck2(2,2:end),'b-','LineWidth',2,'DisplayName',['W = ' num2str(v(k))]);
end
p(2).LineStyle = '--';
p2(2).LineStyle = '--';
legend('show')
```

## Approach 2

Without making it pretty...

```
% Single Isoline
val = 1.2;
contour(X,Y,Z,val), hold on
contour(X,Y,W,val)


% Multiple Isolines
v = [.5 0.75 .85 1];
contour(X,Y,Z,v), hold on
contour(X,Y,W,v)
```

It is straightforward to clean these up for presentation. If `val` is a scalar (single number), then `c1 = contour(X,Y,Z,val);` and `c2 = contour(X,Y,W,val)` gives access to the isoline for each contour plot.