# how to plot non-standard contour plots in R (or Matlab)

Tags: r, matlab, plot, contour, cdf

I would like to plot in R following contour plots representing two dimensional cumulative distributon functions (CDF)

[image]

A CDF in 2 or more dimensions is not unique (Lopes et al. The two-dimensional Kolmogorov-Smirnov test) that's why there are 4 alternative plots (and probably some more).

So far I have no R/Matlab code to show. I don't think it's difficult but most likely very time consuming. There might out there something I could use.

**EDIT**
Type 1 & 4 are more or less covered, but any help with 2 & 3 would be really appreciated.
[image]
[image]

**EDIT2**
Types 2 & 3 using `geom_rect` - as simple as it gets! 
[image]
The sequence of recangles is ordered wrt the eucleadian distance of the data. This means, if we assume this generic ordering, there is possibly only one version of defining a 2D CDF instead of two. That would confirm the statement of Lopes et al.and other that there are only 2^N-1 (here 3) ways to define the CDF.
Any thoughts?

Comment: The one on the left and right seem easy enough to generate using a `z = f(x,y)` approach.  The middle two look more challenging. I think some more info, details, and your code from your attempt would help move this forward.  Related posts: [1 - functions of 2 variables](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16868074/8239061), [2 - contour isolines](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57007211/8239061).

Comment: @SecretAgentMan thanks for the links. I will have a go myself and keep you posted.

Comment: ping me in [this chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204228/discussion-for-https-stackoverflow-com-q-59329270-8239061). I've written a short bit of code to help you get started.  Look forward to seeing your full attempt.

Comment: @SecretAgentMan I am trying to join the chat room, but I was unsuccessful so far. I keep you posted if this changes AND I have something worth showing...